# php class exits and autoload

Tags: php, class, if-statement, autoload

Trying to check if a class exits with php's class_exits function. I however have __autoload on and registered to a function that echoes or exits if the class is not available. The problem is that during the check php class exits function is echoing if(class_exist($class)) returns false which is a undesirable behavior. What can i do to stop this behavior.

```
$file=core_directory.'/plugins/'.$class.'.php';
if(is_readable($file))
require($file);
else
echo " The file:".$file." does not exist on this server";
```

works fine but if this

```
if(class_exists($controller))
{
    return new $controller_name($this);
}
else
{
    return $this->controller_dosnt_exist($controller_name);
}
```

returns false it echos out my __autoload error which is not what i want especially seeing as i want to replace it with exit($msg)

I tried

```
if(new $controller())
{
    return new $controller_name($this);
}
else
{
    return $this->controller_dosnt_exist($controller_name);
}
```

and that works fine so my questions are is my second if statment bad to use for some memory reason or whatever and if so how can i get the desired behavior for my first section of code.

Comment: Is it intended that you use `$controller` and `$controller_name` variables? If so, what are the exact values they hold.

Comment: Hey if `$class` comes from user input, I would suggest "cleaning" the data before calling those functions, and or including them in your output. Null bytes can prevent the `.php` extension from being included in the fully qualified string;

Comment: no they arent user input and they holds strings like "index_controller"

Comment: You could do something like `...if(file_exists($file)) {require($file);} return false;...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misundestood your question in the first time. Here's somesthing you may be looking for:

1st, replace your "echo" with an Exception like this:

```
$file=core_directory.'/plugins/'.$class.'.php';

if(is_readable($file))
    require($file);
else
    throw new Exception("The file:".$file." does not exist on this server");
```

Now, replace your if statement with this:

```
$ret = null;

try{
    $ret = new $controller_name($this); //Idk what you're doint with '$this', so i kept it
}catch(Exception $ex){
    $ret = $this->controller_dosnt_exist($controller_name);
}

return $ret;
```

Comment: ok thanks seems a bit bugged to me tho to cant do my if. So just to wrap. A better solution is to do as this answer says or simply not echo out but instead log the error

Answer (score 0):

Don't echo in the autoloader.  If you need to track these problems, log them to a file somewhere instead.  You can use file_put_contents with the FILE_APPEND flag for a simple implementation.

You could also wrap the class_exists in a ob_start/ob_clean, but that is tremendously ugly.

Comment: okay i see its just i see everyone always echoes or exit('msg'). may have to just log indeed as echoing was a nono for its use

Comment: The best way to handle a missing class in an autoloader is typically to just return and let PHP throw an error about the class not being found, since usually your code can't continue without the class anyway.  In this case, you're testing for the class with class_exists, so perhaps the code with the class_exists should be logging about the class it was missing.